# Match multiple `FieldDecl` inside a `CXXRecordDecl`

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-c++-api, libtooling

I am trying to capture all `struct`s that look like:

```cpp
struct Obj1 {
  int field1;
  double field2;

  template <typename Ar>
  void serialize(Ar& ar) {
    ::serializer(ar, field1, field2);
  }
};
```

I would like to match all `struct`s with a `template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar)` method, and then collect the class `FieldDecl`s to some place. I am currently using the following match (in clang-query):

```
cxxRecordDecl( has( functionTemplateDecl( has( templateTypeParmDecl() ), has( cxxMethodDecl( hasName("serialize"), parameterCountIs(1) ) ) ) ) )
```

and it seems if I do a `fieldDecl` inside `cxxRecordDecl` with `bind` would capture one and only one field. What if I want all `field1`, `field2` and potentially `fieldN`?